# Linking up nested SQLite database tables for android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an android project, and just to let you know I'm a total newb.  I have a project that has multiple tables.  There is a list activity that when clicked on leads to another list activity. The constructor for the top level activity sets the id to the class when the row is created.  The second level activity has as part of its table and data a reference to the id from the top level activity.  I'm not sure how to add the id when I create an object of the second level activity.  Perhaps looking at my code will make the question clearer.

Here is my term class:

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

public class Term {

    private long id;
    private String termsName;
    private String termStartDate;
    private String termEndDate;

    //Constructor
    Term(){

    }

    Term(String termsName, String termStartDate, String termEndDate){
        this.termsName = termsName;
        this.termStartDate = termStartDate;
        this.termEndDate = termEndDate;
    }

    Term(int id, String termsName, String termStartDate, String termEndDate){
        this.id = id;
        this.termsName = termsName;
        this.termStartDate = termStartDate;
        this.termEndDate = termEndDate;
    }

    //G&S id

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //G&S terms name

    public String getTermsName() {
        return termsName;
    }

    public void setTermsName(String termsName) {
        this.termsName = termsName;
    }

    //G&S terms start date

    public String getTermStartDate() {
        return termStartDate;
    }

    public void setTermStartDate(String termStartDate) {
        this.termStartDate = termStartDate;
    }

    //G&S terms end date

    public String getTermEndDate() {
        return termEndDate;
    }

    public void setTermEndDate(String termEndDate) {
        this.termEndDate = termEndDate;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return termsName;
    }
}
```

Here is my course class:

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

public class Course {

    private long id;
    private String courseName;
    private String courseStart;
    private String courseEnd;
    private String courseStatus;
    private String courseMentor;
    private String termId;

    Course(){

    }
```

// need help with this constructor

```
    Course(String courseName, String courseStart, String courseEnd, String courseStatus,
           String courseMentor){
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseStart = courseStart;
        this.courseEnd = courseEnd;
        this.courseStatus = courseStatus;
        this.courseMentor = courseMentor;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseStart() {
        return courseStart;
    }

    public void setCourseStart(String courseStart) {
        this.courseStart = courseStart;
    }

    public String getCourseEnd() {
        return courseEnd;
    }

    public void setCourseEnd(String courseEnd) {
        this.courseEnd = courseEnd;
    }

    public String getCourseStatus() {
        return courseStatus;
    }

    public void setCourseStatus(String courseStatus) {
        this.courseStatus = courseStatus;
    }

    public String getCourseMentor() {
        return courseMentor;
    }

    public void setCourseMentor(String courseMentor) {
        this.courseMentor = courseMentor;
    }

    public String getTermId() {
        return termId;
    }

    public void setTermId(String termId) {
        this.termId = termId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return courseName;
    }
}
```

Here is a DataSource class that creates rows and also classes from data gathered from edit text boxes:

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataSource {

    //Fields
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBOpenHelper helper;

    private String[] allTermColums = {DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID, DBOpenHelper.NAME_OF_TERM,
        DBOpenHelper.TERM_START_DATE, DBOpenHelper.TERM_END_DATE};

    private String[] allCourseColums = {DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_NAME,
        DBOpenHelper.COURSE_START, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_END, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_STATUS,
        DBOpenHelper.COURSE_MENTOR, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID};

    public DataSource(Context context){
        helper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLiteException{
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        helper.close();
    }

    //Create Term
    public Term createTerm(Term term){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.NAME_OF_TERM, term.getTermsName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_START_DATE, term.getTermStartDate());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_END_DATE, term.getTermEndDate());
        long insertId = db.insert(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, null, cv);
        term.setId(insertId);
        return term;
    }

    //Create Course
    public Course createCourse(Course course){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_NAME, course.getCourseName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_START, course.getCourseStart());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_END, course.getCourseEnd());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_STATUS, course.getCourseStatus());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_MENTOR, course.getCourseMentor());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID, course.getTermId());
        long insertId = db.insert(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, null, cv);
        course.setId(insertId);
        return course;
    }

    //Update term
    public void updateTerm(Term term){
        long id = term.getId();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.NAME_OF_TERM, term.getTermsName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_START_DATE, term.getTermStartDate());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_END_DATE, term.getTermEndDate());
        db.update(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, cv, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    //Update Course
    public void updateCourse(Course course){
        long id = course.getId();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_NAME, course.getCourseName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_START, course.getCourseStart());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_END, course.getCourseEnd());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_STATUS, course.getCourseStatus());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_MENTOR, course.getCourseMentor());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID, course.getTermId());
        db.update(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, cv, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    //CursorToTerm method
    private Term cursorToTerm(Cursor cursor){
        Term term  = new Term();
        term.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        term.setTermsName(cursor.getString(1));
        term.setTermStartDate(cursor.getString(2));
        term.setTermEndDate(cursor.getString(3));
        return term;
    }

    //CursonToCourse
    private Course cursorToCourse(Cursor cursor){
        Course course = new Course();
        course.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        course.setCourseName(cursor.getString(1));
        course.setCourseStart(cursor.getString(2));
        course.setCourseEnd(cursor.getString(3));
        course.setCourseStatus(cursor.getString(4));
        course.setCourseMentor(cursor.getString(5));
        return course;
    }

    //Getting all terms
    public List<Term> getAllTerms(){
        List<Term> termList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, allTermColums,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Term term = cursorToTerm(cursor);
            termList.add(term);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return termList;
    }

    //Getting all courses
    public List<Course> getAllCourses(){
        List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, allCourseColums,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Course course = cursorToCourse(cursor);
            courseList.add(course);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return courseList;
    }

    //Getting and creating a single term
    public Term getSingleTermById(long id){
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, allTermColums,
                DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Term term = cursorToTerm(cursor);
        return term;
    }

    //Getting and creating a single course
    public Course getSingleCourseById(long id){
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, allCourseColums,
                DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

       Course course = cursorToCourse(cursor);
        return course;
    }


    //Delete single term
    public void deleteTerm(Term term){
        long id = term.getId();
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }
    //Delete single course
    public void deleteCourse(Course course){
        long id = course.getId();
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    //Delete single term by id
    public void deleteTermById(long id){
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }
    //Delete single course by id
    public void deleteCourseById(long id){
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

}
```

This is the activity that creates a new course from the edit text boxes.  Each course is associated with a term, so first the term is created in the app, then you click onto the term and a course associated with the term is created.  Its linking up the two that I'm struggling with.

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CourseEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button courseAddButton;
    private EditText courseNameEditText;
    private EditText courseStartEditText;
    private EditText courseEndEditText;
    private EditText courseStatusEditText;
    private EditText courseMentorEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_term_edit);


        courseAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_course_button);
        courseNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course_name_edittext);
        courseStartEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course_start_edittext);
        courseEndEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course_end_editext);
        courseStatusEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course_status_editext);
        courseMentorEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course_mentor_editext);

        courseAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Code to test that edit boxes are filled

                if(courseNameEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && courseStartEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && courseEndEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
                        && courseStatusEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                        && courseMentorEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 {
                    Course course = new Course(courseNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                            courseStartEditText.getText().toString(),
                            courseEndEditText.getText().toString()),
                            courseStatusEditText.getText().toString()),
                            courseMentorEditText.getText().toString());
                    DataSource ds = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
                    ds.open();
                    ds.createCourse(course);
                    ds.close();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see from the datasource when I call the createterm() method, it adds all of the appropriate columns to the database then updates the id, then returns the term.  When I try to run createcourse() method, I'm not sure how to create a course object that is able to get the proper id from the associated term.

Comment: You need to retrive the stored ID for the Term, and pass it to the new Course object you want to store.

Comment: I thought maybe I could just use an intent to continue to pass along the id to the following activities.

Comment: @Jonas452 could you provide me an example on how to do this?  I'm not sure how to get a reference to the correct term.